# Why does Python return [15] for [0xfor x in (1, 2, 3)]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-precedence, short-circuiting

When running the following line:

```
>>> [0xfor x in (1, 2, 3)]
```

I expected Python to return an error.

Instead, the REPL returns:

> `[15]`

What can possibly be the reason?

Comment: Note that Python sees this as `[0xf or x in (1, 2, 3)]`. You've actually found a minor bug in Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter, as it renders the `0xfor` without colouring the `or` ;)

Comment: Quite unexpected... obviously this is useful for codegolfing, but it doesn't feel really consistent at all with the rest of the syntax. IMHO I'd have preferred if strings of consecutive alphanumeric characters were always considered single tokens.

Comment: I feel like it's a bug in the parser. For the record, it gives the same result with `3or 4` or `"hello"and 5`. I suspect it's a consequence to accommodate cases for binary operators such as "3>4", but in the case of comparison ops, it's not a straight connection as you can't do `3and5`. I posted in python-dev and see what they say

Comment: Also note that it's not due to the new parser. The behavior is found also in python 2.7

Comment: Storchaka verbatim "it does not contradict specification, but looks pretty confusing, so we
will likely change specification and implementation to prevent confusion.". It is also known since 2018.

Comment: @StefanoBorini `"hello"and 5` and `3>5` are different. `"` and `>` are not valid in identifiers or other forms of expressions. What is unexpected is that a string of pure alphanumeric characters (i.e. `[a-z0-9]`) can be interpreted as 2 tokens instead of one "randomly"

Answer (score 104, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Python reads the expression as `[0xf or (x in (1, 2, 3))]`, because:

1. The [Python tokenizer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1544).
2. [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

It never raises `NameError` thanks to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - if the expression left to the `or` operator is a truthy value, Python will never try to evaluate the right side of it.

#### Parsing hexadecimal numbers

First, we have to understand how Python reads hexadecimal numbers.

On [tokenizer.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c)'s huge `tok_get` function, we:

1. [Find](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1545) the first `0x`.
2. [Keep reading the next characters](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1561) as long as they're in the range of 0-f.

The parsed token, `0xf` (as "o" is not in the range of 0-f), will eventually get passed to the PEG parser, which will convert it to the decimal value `15` (see Appendix A).

We still have to parse the rest of the code, `or x in (1, 2, 3)]`, which leaves as with the following code:

```
[15 or x in (1, 2, 3)]
```

#### Operator precedence

Because `in` have higher [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `or`, we might expect `x in (1, 2, 3)` to evaluate first.

That is troublesome situation, as `x` doesn't exist and will raise a `NameError`.

#### `or` is lazy

Fortunately, Python supports [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) as `or` is a lazy operator: if the left operand is equivalent to `True`, Python won't bother evaluating the right operand.

We can see it using the `ast` module:

```py
parsed = ast.parse('0xfor x in (1, 2, 3)', mode='eval')
ast.dump(parsed)
```

Output:

```py
    Expression(
        body=BoolOp(
            op=Or(),
            values=[
                Constant(value=15),   # <-- Truthy value, so the next operand won't be evaluated.
                Compare(
                    left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
                    ops=[In()],
                    comparators=[
                        Tuple(elts=[Constant(value=1), Constant(value=2), Constant(value=3)], ctx=Load())
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
    )
```

So the final expression is equal to `[15]`.

---

#### Appendix A: The PEG parser

On [pegen.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/pegen.c#L947)'s `parsenumber_raw` function, we can find how Python treats leading zeros:

```c
    if (s[0] == '0') {
        x = (long)PyOS_strtoul(s, (char **)&end, 0);
        if (x < 0 && errno == 0) {
            return PyLong_FromString(s, (char **)0, 0);
        }
    }
```

[`PyOS_strtoul`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/mystrtoul.c#L212) is in `Python/mystrtoul.c`.

Inside mystrtoul.c, the parser looks at [one character after the `0x`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/mystrtoul.c#L110). If it's an hexadecimal character, Python sets the base of the number to be 16:

```c
            if (*str == 'x' || *str == 'X') {
                /* there must be at least one digit after 0x */
                if (_PyLong_DigitValue[Py_CHARMASK(str[1])] >= 16) {
                    if (ptr)
                        *ptr = (char *)str;
                    return 0;
                }
                ++str;
                base = 16;
            } ...
```

Then it [parses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/mystrtoul.c#L212) the rest of the number as long as the characters are in the range of 0-f:

```c
    while ((c = _PyLong_DigitValue[Py_CHARMASK(*str)]) < base) {
        if (ovlimit > 0) /* no overflow check required */
            result = result * base + c;
        ...
        ++str;
        --ovlimit;
    }
```

[Eventually](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/mystrtoul.c#L240), it sets the pointer to point the last character that was scanned - which is one character past the last hexadecimal character:

```
    if (ptr)
        *ptr = (char *)str;
```

---

#### Thanks

- [CSI_Tech_Dept](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/mqfb67/why_does_python_return_15_for_0xfor_x_in_1_2_3/gufu5yo/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) from reddit for referring me to the correct section in the tokenizer.c file.
- [The original Tweet](https://twitter.com/nedbat/status/1382027078816653319).

Comment: Sometimes I think Python was never intended to be a real product. 670 lines of tokenizing in a single method? Who wants to maintain that?

Comment: @defalt What space are you talking about? There is no space between `0x` and `f` in the line being asked about.

Comment: @ThomasWeller A) for a tokenizer, that's not bad. B) Python is not a "product", real or otherwise, and indeed wasn't intended as one. It started life as a teaching language.

Answer (score 28):

Other answers already tell what exactly happens. But for me, the interesting part was that the operator is recognized even without whitespace between the number and it. Actually, my first thought was "Wow, Python has a weird parser".

But before judging too harshly, maybe I should ask my other friends what they think:

Perl:

```
$ perl -le 'print(0xfor 3)'
15
```

Lua:

```
$ lua5.3 -e 'print(0xfor 4)'
15
```

Awk doesn't have `or`, but it has `in`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { a[15]=1; print(0x0fin a); }'
1
```

Ruby? (I don't really know it, but let's guess):

```
$ ruby -e 'puts 0x0for 5'
15
```

Yep, FWIW, Python is not alone, all of those other script-type languages also recognize the alphabetic operators even if stuck immediately to the back of a numeric constant.

Comment: If you use bash or zsh, you can also try this: `echo $(( 34#0xfor -15 ))` ― This is different from the other cases, though, because there is no hidden `or` operator here.

Answer (score 6):

As others have explained, it’s just the hexadecimal number `0xf` followed by the operator `or`. Operators generally don’t need surrounding spaces, unless necessary to avoid ambiguity. In this case, the letter `o` cannot be part of a hexadecimal number, so there is no ambiguity. See the [section on whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens) in the Python language reference.

The rest of the line is not evaluated because of short-circuit evaluation, although it is parsed and compiled, of course.

Using that same “trick” you can write similarly obfuscated Python code that doesn’t throw exceptions, for example:

```
>>> 0xbin b'in'
False
>>> 0xbis 1000
False
>>> 0b1and 0b1is 0b00
False
>>> 0o1if 0b1else Oy1then
1
```